# Magento 2.1 login issue on local host

Tags: magento-2.1

When i am trying to login from user side for which i registered for it. even if right or wrong credential entered the *required field shows up and stay on same page i am using magento 2.1.2 and chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

Try following step:

1. Delete var/cache/*, var/generation/*, var/page_cache/*
2. Make 777 permission for **var** folder
3. Delete pub/static/* (except .htaccess)
4. Make 777 permission for pub/static, pub/media